# i can't debug a simple error in shellscript

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

i am learning shell script..

this works well

```
#!/bin/bash
temp = "test" 
if["$temp" = "test"]; then
   echo "true"
else
   echo "false"
fi
```

but this does not work

```
#!/bin/bash 
while (true) ; do 
test=$(exec /usr/bin/mysql -u root -p"password" databasename  -N -s -e "select seq  from table limit 1 ") 
echo $test; 
if[ "$test" = "" ]; then 
    exec ./do_Something.sh $test 
else 
    echo "." 
fi 
    sleep 30 
done
```

the error message

```
./tes.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `then' 
./test.sh: line 5: `  if[ "$test" = "" ]; then'
```

What went wrong?

Comment: I don't think the first script should work, either.

Comment: i am with @Barmar .. yes the space is missing in the first script as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give a space between `if` and `[`.